# Printing information from the text fields <input>

Tags: html, input, textfield

I have three text fields that I am trying to summarize on the screen later.

I tried to get the input data with getelementbyid and getelementsbyname.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <form id="frm1">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br> Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <p>Click "Try it" to show the full name:</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hey ," + fname + " " + lname;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It is supposed to show Hey ,Firstname Lastname

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<form id="frm1" >
  First name: <input type="text" id='fname' ><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" id='lname' ><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Click "Try it" to show the full name:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var fname = document.getElementById("fname"); 
var lname = document.getElementById("lname"); 
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML  = "Hey ,"+fname.value+ " "+lname.value;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This should work for you. You have to give value of the html elements into javascript variables, then you can use .value of those variables in the innerHTML function.

Comment: It works! Thank you. How could I use div to read from the form?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you couldn't get `getElementsByName` working, but it will do the trick:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <form id="frm1">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br> Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <p>Click "Try it" to show the full name:</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var fname = document.getElementsByName('fname')[0].value,
          lname = document.getElementsByName('lname')[0].value;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hey ," + fname + " " + lname;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the inputs by ID but you have not given the inputs an ID, just the name variable

Comment: Will div help here?

Comment: Will work with anything as long as you use the correct call to access the element. So if the DIV has a unique ID you can use getElementById to access its value or change its innerHtml

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form id="frm1" >
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" ><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" ><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Click "Try it" to show the full name:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hey ,"+document.getElementById("frm1").fname.value+ " "+document.getElementById("frm1").lname.value;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, just one stupid question. Could it be done with <div> ?

Comment: I could not get the question. You want to say that instead of a form you have a div ? In that case put ids to your input fields. Like this :  First name: <input type="text" name="lname" id=fname ><br> <input type="text" name="fname" id=lname ><br>  and then in my function get the value of these fields using their respective ids